# URL Rewriting I don't want to show index.php in url

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am running my php applications on

**http://localhost:8085/**

My Directory Structure is like this:
C:\wamp\www\website

I have placed the .htaccess file in website folder.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
#Turn on the RewriteEngine
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /website/
#Rules
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php
</IfModule>
```

When ever i click on the index.php it takes me to the http://localhost:8085/ home page which is wrong i want to got to http://localhost:8085/website.

Please guide me

Comment: Another test you can do it to rename this .htaccess and then click on link again to see whether problem is fixed or not.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add your `website` before index.php like,

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /website/index.php
```

**Updated,** try the full code,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /website/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /website/index.php [L]
```

Note: You need to use `http://localhost:8085/website/` as base URL in every link which is used in your site, otherwise it will redirect to `http://localhost:8085/` like,

```
<a href="http://localhost:8085/website/index.php">Home page</a>
```

Alternatively, do not use a `/` before any `href` and use your file name as it is for example,

```
<a href="index.php">Home page</a>
```

If you are using `<a href="/index.php">Home page</a>` it will redirect to index page of URL `http://localhost:8085/`

You can make a Virtual Host to access it directly https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/name-based.html

Comment: After this change website is not opening it gives internal server error

Comment: Since Danish is using `RewriteBase /website/` there is no need to use full path of `/website/index.php` in the rule.

Comment: Still same issue now the website is working fine but it is re-directing me to localhost

Comment: @DanishSubhu are you using any Framework like codeigniter? If yes or not then you need to use `http://localhost:8085/website/` as your base URL.

Comment: @anubhava I have lots of projects which are not working without specifying the RewriteBase again in RewriteRule. And the same issue occurs if I remove it from the Rule.

Comment: You might be having some other rule issue that I cannot guess but this is whole intent behind `RewriteBase` directive so that one doesn't need to repeat same fullpath again and again in all the `RewriteRule`

Comment: @RohanKumar I am not using any framework. Just using plain php.U want me to use the RewriteBase as - http://localhost:8085/website/ ??

Comment: @DanishSubhu then you need to use `http://localhost:8085/website/` as base URL and in every link which is used in your site, otherwise it will redirect to `http://localhost:8085/`. You can make a Virtual Host to access it directly https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/name-based.html

Comment: @anubhava No other code, other than given in my answer which is used for redirecting.

Comment: In that case OP's code in question is correct and he's having some other issue.

Comment: I have replaced RewriteBase to  http://localhost:8085/website/ still getting redirected to localhost

Comment: There are 2 situations where the problem occurs 1st From htaccess, 2nd from Code URLs. And I've given solutions for both. Hopefully it will work for @DanishSubhu.

Comment: @RohanKumar I am new to php I am not generatinganything  dynamically it is just a simple link as <a href="index.php"/> from other section so I guess it can't be the code error, so that means it is from .htacesss as if i remove the rules it loads the index.php and it can be seen in the url